# Streaming playlist in rm format to j2me Midelt

Tags: audio, java-me, mobile, streaming, video-streaming

I am developing internet radio that to be consumed by j2me midelt MIDP2 clcd1.1 , as per my knowledge j2me can consume only RM and AMR format over rtsp or http .

which streaming shall i use, i know about helix , but can i used DSS For that ? or any other free alternative